# Parameter with dictionary path

Tags: python, json

I am very new to Python and am not very familiar with the data structures in Python.

I am writing an automatic JSON parser in Python, the JSON message is read into a dictionary using Ultra-JSON:

```
jsonObjs = ujson.loads(data)
```

Now, if I try something like:
`jsonObjs[param1][0][param2]` it works fine
However, I need to get the path from an external source (I read it from the DB), we initially thought we'll just write in the DB:

```
myPath = [param1][0][param2]
```

and then try to access:

```
jsonObjs[myPath]
```

But after a couple of failures I realized I'm trying to access:

```
jsonObjs[[param1][0][param2]]
```

Is there a way to fix this without parsing myPath?

Many thanks for your help and advice

Answer (score 3):

Store the keys in a format that preserves type information, e.g. JSON, and then [use `reduce()` to perform recursive accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11475052/20862) on the structure.

Comment: Hi, this is a very nice trick unfortunately part of the path is string and not just integers, so it doesn't work

Comment: @Sigal: Read the first part of my answer.

Comment: I am very new to Python so perhaps I don't understand it well enough. I ended up writing it myself