# "Remember" parent keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary of this structure:

```
x = {
  "a": {
      "b": {
         "c": 1
      }
  }
}
```

I create a function that accepts a structure like `some_func(structure={"a.b.c":2})`

I need this function to traverse x and change the value of c to 2.
The depth of the dictionary is unknown to the function. So it has to rely on the structure passed to it.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474706/using-dict-keys-in-python-as-values-in-a-different-dict

Comment: What do you mean that you "have a JSON"? JSON is a file structure--is what you show in a file? The leading `x =` prevents it from being a valid JSON. Do you mean that you have a "data structure" with the name `x`?

Comment: @RoryDaulton : I did not word my question properly.. I do have a JSON file that I read into x and then try to assign a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive algorithm or `functools.reduce` to cycle your nested dictionary structure. Below is an example of the latter. For illustration, we assign multiple values via a dictionary.

```
x = {"a": {"b": {"c": 1, "d": 3}}}

from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

def set_single_val(dataDict, mapKeys, value):
    mapList = mapKeys.split('.')
    reduce(getitem, mapList[:-1], dataDict)[mapList[-1]] = value

def set_vals(x, structure={}):
    for k, v in structure.items():
        set_single_val(x, k, v)

set_vals(x, structure={"a.b.c":2, "a.b.d":4})

print(x)

{'a': {'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 4}}}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I hava made a library that does what you ask, and more, [Prodict](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict).

```
from prodict import Prodict

x = {
  "a": {
      "b": {
         "c": 1
      }
  }
}

p = Prodict.from_dict(x)
p.a.b.c = 2

print(p)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': 2}}}
```

Comment: That and that it doesn't do what the OP is asking, probably.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that helped.

Comment: I see this with your lib: 
` >>> import prodict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/prodict/__init__.py", line 21
    val: cls = cls(**d)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: @AmolDeodhar, I just checked and it worked. Prodict requires Python 3.6+.

Comment: Didn't notice the version required... I am working on 3.5

Comment: @AmolDeodhar I strongly suggest 3.6, type hints have great benefit and Prodict also uses type hints.